# Debugging Hard Drive Issues

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, macos

My SSD system disk is apparently unmounting about an hour after booting, causing "drive is not configured" errors when trying to read any files, and the Spinning Beach Ball of Death.  Disk Utility and TechTools Pro report the drive as being OK, passing all tests, and the drive's SMART information shows all reported attributes as being nominal.  I suspect that the SSD's drive controller or the motherboard's SATA controller is to blame.

Are there any system log files or other tools that may lend some insight into what is actually happening?

Comment: It would help if you print the output of smartctl here (part of smartmontools): http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki